# Factor out zero-valued function in the extended complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is: in the extended complex plane, do we have

$$
\frac{(z-a)f(z)}{(z-a)g(z)}=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}
$$

when $z=a$?

This question looks quite dumb. If we are not dealing with extended complex plane, then we can only talk about the limit when $z$ approaches to $a$ and the answer is yes. However, in the extened plane, we are allowed to divide by $0$. So, I am wondering how to rationalize this argument in the extended plane because there are many proofs that freely factor functions without justification of such singularities. It really bothers me in one of the exercises in Ahlfor's Complex Analysis. This exercise asks us to prove
$$
\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{P(\alpha_k)}{Q'(\alpha_k)(z-\alpha_k)}
$$
if $Q(z)$ has distinct roots $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ and $\deg f<n$. The answer I came out is to write $Q(z)=q(z-\alpha_1)...(z-\alpha_n)$ and multiply the right side by $Q(z)$. Simplying it, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\prod^{n}_{i=1}(z-a_i)P({\alpha_k})}{\prod_{j\neq k}(a_j-a_k)(z-
\alpha_k)}.
$$
If we are allowed to factor out $z-\alpha_k$ in the fraction, then we can conclude that this expression is equal to $P(z)$ since it agrees with $P(z)$ on all of $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n.$ If this argument fails, then is there any alternative way to prove the statement that avoid this unrigorous argument? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Depends on the level of formality you want. You're basically just defining the value of the function at the missing point to be the unique value of a holomorphic extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maybe a little bit of abuse of notation, but it's very common in complex analysis to ignore [removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) of functions. In other words,
if you have a function $f(z)$ that is defined in some neighbourhood of $a$ such that it has a unique holomorphic continuation onto $a$, then we tend to treat that continuation as being the "same" as the original function $f$.